# Can I program in Java with someone else on the same project at the same time?

Tags: eclipse, java

Is there anything such as an eclipse plugin that will allow code to be updated and used on a server, allowing for me to work on the same Java project as someone else at the same exact time? To explain more, lets say me and someone else needed a lot of classes for game characters, and we want to program two different characters at the same time to speed it up, is that possible without having someone develop in eclipse, and someone else in notepad++ and add them together? Sorry if this was already asked, I can't explain this to google lol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is called a version control

Links:

- [Git](http://git-scm.com) (open source)
- [CVS](http://www.nongnu.org/cvs/) (open source)
- [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org) (open source

Just google them and you will find lots of information about them and how to use them.

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer if you consider an acceptable answer ;)

Comment: I actually was gonna pick this one, but there is a timer, I can accept it in 2 minutes at the time I'm sending this. Again, thanks!

Comment: I don't think anybody uses CVS anymore.  I use SVN at work, but I prefer Git for my personal development. Great answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are many solutions that can help in many aspects of the problem.  As others have pointed out [GIT](http://git-scm.com/), [SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/) and other [version control] solutions.

However if what you want to do simultaneous coding (as in LITERALLY at the same time as if two of you were sitting on the same computer (but of course you are on separate computers) then there solutions like [Saros](http://www.saros-project.org) and [Xpairtise](http://xpairtise.sourceforge.net) that plug into eclipse and help you do pair programming.

Have a look and see if any of those help.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Use a source/version control software like SVN.

It stores and updates code on a central repository and provides added control of versioning.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try TeamViewer which allows screen share and keyboard/mouse sharing.